# with Ansible and apt, how do I update bash to for the remotely exploitable security vulnerability CVE-2014-6271?

Tags: ubuntu, patch, ansible, apt, shellshock-bash-bug

Given [bash's remote code execution vulnerability announced on Sept 24 2014](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/650), how can I update my apt-based systems using Ansible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my preferred solution in a fairly homogenous environment. The advantage of this is the update won't take a lot of time in the future, unlike the `version=latest` pattern others are using.

```
- name: update apt cache if not done today
  apt: update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=86400

# http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/650
- name: ensure secure ansible, ubuntu 1204 edition
  apt: pkg=bash=4.2-2ubuntu2.5 state=present
  when: ansible_distribution=='Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_version=='12.04'

- name: ensure secure ansible, ubuntu 1404 edition
  apt: pkg=bash=4.3-7ubuntu1.3 state=present
  when: ansible_distribution=='Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_version=='14.04'

# based on the following gist and comments below. there have been several exploits, this covers them well.
# https://gist.github.com/kacy/2b9408af04c71fab686e
- name: ensure bash is not vulnerable to 201409 problem
  shell: "foo='() { echo not patched; }' bash -c foo"
  register: command_result
  ignore_errors: yes
  failed_when: "'command not found' not in command_result.stderr"
```

Explanation: updating the apt-cache is expensive if done many times per day. The cache time can be adjusted. The code actually tests to make sure the vulnerability is fixed- tests are good. This will highlight any hosts that aren't covered by the distributions/versions coded.

SO user @jarv [posted a great solution](https://github.com/edx/configuration/blob/master/playbooks/roles/security/tasks/security-ubuntu.yml) too. Instead of always updating apt, it only does so if the problem hasn't been fixed. This is the fastest solution possible (in this answer, at least). jarv has also [added a distribution test in the linked repo](https://github.com/edx/configuration/blob/master/playbooks/roles/security/tasks/main.yml), useful for heterogeneous environments.

```
- name: Check if we are vulnerable
  shell: executable=/bin/bash env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable'  bash -c "echo this is a test"
  register: test_vuln

- name: Apply bash security update if we are vulnerable
  apt: name=bash state=latest update_cache=true
  when: "'vulnerable' in test_vuln.stdout"

- name: Check again and fail if we are still vulnerable
  shell: executable=/bin/bash env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable'  bash -c "echo this is a test"
  when: "'vulnerable' in test_vuln.stdout"
  register: test_vuln
  failed_when: "'vulnerable' in test_vuln.stdout"
```

There are other ways. Michael DeHaan, creator of Ansible, and the official @ansible account tweeted a few solutions:

[Here's a one-liner](https://twitter.com/svg/status/514836542142304256):

```
ansible all -m apt -a 'update_cache=yes name=bash state=latest'
```

[Here's a update-and-check solution](https://gist.github.com/kacy/2b9408af04c71fab686e):

```
- name: update apt
  command: apt-get update

- name: update bash
  command: apt-get --only-upgrade install bash

- name: check bash fix
  command: env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'error' not in command_result.stderr"
```

Comment: Here is another solution - https://github.com/edx/configuration/blob/master/playbooks/roles/security/tasks/security-ubuntu.yml Checks to see if the vulnerability exists before the apt-get update.

Comment: and how to extend for testing against CVE-2014-7169 which according to could be tested with https://shellshocker.net/ ?

    env X='() { (a)=>\' sh -c "echo date"; cat echo

and no date should be printed... may be smth like

    env X='() { (a)=>\' sh -c "echo echo vulnerable"; cat echo

could be used to and should not get "vulnerable" as the last string?

Comment: @YaroslavHalchenko if I understand your question, yes, that's what "vulnerable" tests for. If it prints vulnerable, you need to update.

Comment: The previous vulnerability check is incomplete. Since the first patch was released, further vulnerabilities have been found. A complete vulnerability check would also include this one liner. `foo='() { echo not patched; }' bash -c foo`

Comment: @apotek thanks- researched and verified locally. I'll edit.